ActiveMQ Artemis connection timeout in Spring Boot
I have some troubles with sending message to ActiveMQ Artemis in Spring Boot:
Uncategorized exception occurred during JMS processing; nested exception is ActiveMQConnectionTimedOutException[errorType=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT message=AMQ219013: Timed out waiting to receive cluster topology. Group:null]

I use the apache/activemq-artemis:latest-alpine Docker container. I wasn't configure it and open 5672 port.
If I try to send message by JMS template I got this error.
My beans (on Kotlin):
@EnableJms
@Configuration
class JmsConfig {
    @Bean
    fun jmsTemplate(connectionFactory: ConnectionFactory): JmsTemplate {
        val jmsTemplate = JmsTemplate(connectionFactory)
        jmsTemplate.messageConverter = messageConverter()
        return jmsTemplate
    }

    @Bean
    fun messageConverter(): MessageConverter {
        val converter = MappingJackson2MessageConverter()

        converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT)
        converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type")

        return converter
    }
}

@Configuration
class ActiveMQConfig {

    @Bean
    fun connectionFactory(): ConnectionFactory {
        return ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:5672?protocols=STOMP,AMQP,MQTT", "artemis", "artemis")
    }
}

The place where I send message
@Service
class EmailGateway (
    private val template: JmsTemplate,
) {
    fun sendEmail(to: String, letter: Letter) {
        template.convertAndSend("test-queue", EmailInfo(to, letter))
    }
}

EmailInfo is a business logic class, just class with fields.
My depedendencies
dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-quartz")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-artemis")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.2.0")
    implementation("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.12.5")
    implementation("javax.jms:javax.jms-api:2.0.1")
    implementation("org.apache.activemq:artemis-jakarta-client:2.33.0")
    implementation("org.apache.activemq:artemis-jakarta-server:2.33.0")
    implementation("org.apache.activemq:artemis-jms-server:2.33.0")
    implementation("org.apache.activemq:artemis-jms-client:2.33.0")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail")
    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}

If I turn off ActiveMQ Artemis the error will be changed to:
Uncategorized exception occurred during JMS processing; nested exception is ActiveMQNotConnectedException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=AMQ219007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]

I think I need to configure my ActiveMQ Artemis, but I didn't find some extra settings in my case.
Spring Boot guidelines tell what I just need to use JMS template.
P.S. in embedded configuration all works correctly

Your ActiveMQConnectionFactory is configured to use port 5672. This ConnectionFactory will use the Core protocol. However, in the default broker configuration port 5672 is configured exclusively for AMQP. Try using this instead:
return ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616", "artemis", "artemis")


Thank you! Can you tell me please how can I change default protocol connection? I thought I can do it using different ports or query parameters

In short, you need to use a different client implementation (i.e. library). For example, if you want to use JMS over AMQP then you should use the Qpid JMS client implementation. If you need further details please ask a new question about this.

I need to use STOMP protocol. Can you send me some library for work with it, please?

You need to use STOMP from your Spring Boot application?

Yes, I need to use it

To my knowledge there is no JMS client implementation which uses STOMP as the wire protocol. Therefore you won't be able to use any of the Spring JMS integration components. Spring itself may provide some kind of STOMP client, but I'm not a Spring expert so I'm not sure. Again, I encourage you to ask a new question about this.

Okey, if I decided to use not Spring Boot configuration. How can I do it?

We've drifted way off topic from your original question. The purpose of comments is to clarify, not ask entirely new questions. Please create a new question regarding your STOMP use-case. I couldn't answer it in these comments anyway.
